# How to handle 1000 of tables in one scene in javafx without hang?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I am working on Project on which around 1000 table view on a single page is exit.I had given a scroll bar for it but it is not as smooth as intended to be.So Some how can I draw the table which fits within the screen or window. Then when user wants to scroll down it will draw the other table.I donot want to use pagination provided by javafx .I prefer to have a scroll bar but in the beginning instead of displaying all the table it will display 10 or 15 tables whichever fits within the screen.Any help on this will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Pagination` instead. Each page will create it's own table every time it's opened. When you provide a page index to the page factory then retrieve the necessary data according to that index. Only one istance of Table View will exist in the memory.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that it has helped. You may mark the answer as solving your problem then)